# Local Pagination With Progressive Loading

Tags: tabulator

I'm making use of Tabulator in a project and am utilizing progressive loading. The question I have, is it possible to still do local pagination with progressive loading?

With progressive loading, all of my rows appear on a single page, albeit downloaded in the background. Is is possible to still have progressive loading, but have them populate the table in pages? I'd like to make use of filtering and sorting, but don't want filtering and sorting to go back to the server.

Thanks in advance,
Jon

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you cannot use pagination at the same time as progressive loading.

The progressive loading system actually hijacks the pagination system behind the scenes to manage loading of data in chunks so it is not possible to use the two systems at the same time.